# How do I install MacteXtras into my macbook?

Tags: mactex

I bought a macbook recently and install mactex, but I want to add macteXtras since I want to use spell checker. Can anyone tell me how to do it? I use windows before.

BTW, is that necessary to add macteXtras? Is there any better solutions?

Thank you!

Comment: If you do a standard installation of MacTeX it adds all of the GUI and support stuff, and that includes the spell checker. Thus you should already have it available: have you checked?

Answer (score 2):

A full install of MacTeX includes the [Excalibur](http://excalibur.sourceforge.net) spell checker, which is installed in `/Applications/TeX`. This is a standalone application, not integrated with most modern text editors.

If you want to install additional spell checkers, you can download MacTeXtras.zip from TUG; there is a link on [this page](https://tug.org/mactex/mactextras.html). There is also [documentation](https://tug.org/mactex/mactextras/WhatIsHere.pdf) which describes the contents. Most of this was included in MacTeX proper at one time, but there's no longer room for it on the TeX Collection DVD.